# How do I make an iterator that goes through a list randomly until each item in the list is gone through once? No duplicates

Tags: java

I want to make a class that iterates through a list randomly, but I've been having trouble coding up the methods/constructors. Here's what I have so far.

```
package iterators;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;

import nodes.DLLNode;

public class DLLIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

private DLLNode<E> current;
private boolean iterateForward;

Random random = new Random();
private DLLNode<E> head;
int size;
int count;
boolean array[];


public DLLIterator(DLLNode<E> head, DLLNode<E> tail, boolean iterateForward, boolean iterateRandom, boolean array ) {
    
    this.head = head;
    this.iterateForward  = iterateForward;
    this.size = size;
    current = head;
    count = 0;
    this.array = new boolean[size];
    
    if (iterateForward ) {
        current = head;
    }
    else {
        current = tail;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    
    if (iterateForward) { 
    return current != null;
    }
        
    return count > size;
    

    
}

@Override
public E next() {
    
    if (iterateForward) {
        E temp = current.getData();
        current = current.getNext();
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        
        int size = array.length;
        int min = 0;
        int range = size - min;
        current = head;
        for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++) {
            int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range)+ min;

            while(array[rand]!=true) {
                array[rand]=true;
                count++;
            
            }
            return current.getData();
        }
```

It's telling me that this.size has no effect, but I'm not sure why. The purpose of iterateforward is to go through the list from head to tail, although my main concern is IterateRandom. For the hasNext() method, I understand the purpose of the if iterateforward = true, but I'm not understanding the "return count > size", and I'm not sure if that's correct. I'm assuming it means if count is greater than size, return true, and it ends the loop, but does it end up working here? As for the next method, is there anything in there I'm doing wrong? I'm filling a boolean array with a random integer, and the while loop makes sure that I don't get any duplicates. Is there anything here I'm doing wrong/can improve? I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: `this.size = size;` has no effect because the constructor has no argument called `size`. So both sides of that statement refer to the same variable and you are assigning a variable to itself.

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how I didn't notice that, thank you!